# If I want to prove that $M^{\perp}$is a closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, inner-products, orthogonality

If I want to prove that $M^{\perp}$is a closed

Can I say because it is the inverse image of $0$ by continuos function ( projection operator )

Comment: Yes, that is a valid method of proof

Comment: Alternatively, it is the intersection of a family of closed sets - the kernels of the linear functionals $y \mapsto \langle y,x\rangle$ for each $x\in M$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are saying is absolutely correct. There is another way, more simple and basic, to see this. Let $x$ be a limit point of $M^{\perp}$, i.e,. there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ in $M^{\perp}$ such that $x_n \longrightarrow x$. Since inner product is continuous, it follows that for any fixed $y$; $\langle x_n,y\rangle \longrightarrow \langle x,y\rangle$. But $\langle x_n, y\rangle = 0$ for all $y\in M$, therefore, $\langle x,y\rangle = 0$ for all $y\in M$, i.e., $x\in M^{\perp}$. Hence $M^{\perp}$ is closed.

Comment: Hi how are you sir I want to ask you question if I want to connect with you , because sometime I want some help in my study so I want to ask you , do you have email or another way to connect with you sir please